# The radius of convergence $ R $ of the series $ \sum (a_n)^{-1}z^n $ is $R \leq R_1^{-1}$. Give an example when the inequalty is strict.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $a_n \neq 0$ for every $ n $, then the radius of convergence $ R $ of the serie $ \sum (a_n)^{-1}z^n $ satisfy $R \leq R_1^{-1}$. Give an example when the inequality is strict.

**My proof:**

From the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, we have that:

$ R_1=\dfrac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty}(|a_n|)^{1/n}} $, and

$R=\dfrac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty}\left( \dfrac{1}{|a_n|}\right) ^{1/n}}  \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n \to \infty}\left( \dfrac{1}{|a_n|}\right) ^{1/n} $

Then

$\dfrac{1}{R} \cdot \dfrac{1}{R_1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left( \dfrac{1}{|a_n|}\right) ^{1/n} \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left( |a_n|\right) ^{1/n}$

$\hspace{13mm} \geq \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left( \dfrac{1}{|a_n|} \cdot |a_n| \right) ^{1/n} = 1 $ (For the suprem property).

So, $ \dfrac{1}{R} \cdot \dfrac{1}{R_1} \geq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{R_1} \geq R$

$ \therefore R \leq (R_1)^{-1}$.

But I am missing the example. Can anyone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n=2^n,\,n=2k$, and $a_n=1/2^n,\,n=2k+1$.  Then the inequality is strict, because $R=1/4R_1^{-1}$.